# Why does CNNs usually have a stem?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Most cutting-edge/famous CNN architectures have a stem that does not use a block like the rest of the part of the network, instead, most architectures use plain Conv2d or pooling in the stem without special modules/layers like a shortcut(residual), an inverted residual, a ghost conv, and so on.
Why is this? Are there experiments/theories/papers/intuitions behind this?

examples of stems:
classic ResNet: Conv2d+MaxPool:
[image: resnet config]

bag of tricks ResNet-C: 3*Conv2d+MaxPool, 
even though 2 Conv2d can form the exact same structure as a classic residual block as shown below in [figure 2], there is no shortcut in stem:
[image: resnet-c][image: classic residual block]

**there are many other examples that have similar observations, such as EfficientNet, MobileNet, GhostNet, SE-Net, and so on.**

cite:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01187 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this is done in order to quickly downsample an input image with strided convolutions of quite large kernel size (5x5 or 7x7) so that further layers can effectively do their work with much less computational complexity.

Answer (score 1):

This is because these specialized modules can do no more than just convolutions. The difference is in the trainability of the resulting architecture. For example, the skip connections in ResNet are meant to bypass some layers when these are still so badly trained that they do not propagate the useful information from the input to the output. However, when fully trained, the skip connections could in theory be completely removed (or integrated) since the information can still propagate throught the layers that would otherwise be skipped. However, when you are using a backbone that you dont intend to train yourself, it does not make sence to include architectural features that are aimed at trainability. Instead, you can "compless" the backbone leaving only relatively fundamental operations and freeze all weights. This saves computational costs both when training the head as well as in the final deployment.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense in some cases, but it seems like not all architectural modules are for trainability. For example, inception modules allow better generalization and allow the model to choose the path that is most "useful" for inference, despite such benefit in terms of both accuracy and generalization, Inception still uses no Inception module in stems. This is also true for DenseNet, where its layers are designed to gradually increase its channels, and it allows any layers to communicate with each other. Many CNNs have their modules for not just trainability, but also acc/generalize.

Answer (score 1):

Stem layers work as a compression mechanism over the initial image.
This leads to a fast reduction in the spatial size of the activations, reducing memory and computational costs.